# library for .desktop files

Tags: software-rec, libraries, .desktop

How can I read `.desktop` files without having to (re)invent the wheel? 
Is there a Python or C library that is available in the Ubuntu repos? 
Or something with a command line front-end
that could be used in any language?

`xdg-tools` does only installation and validation. `pyxdg` only returns the strings for each key. I want something higher level corresponding to how it is meant to be used according to the spec, not just a ini-file-parsing library. For example, I want escaping and quoting of `%f`, `%F`, `%u`, `%U`, and `%d` etc., of the Exec key, those additional application actions, etc. 
I do not want to re-implement (nor read all the details of) the spec, because I am sure there exists some implementation of it already used by GNOME KDE, Ubuntu Unity, etc.

Comment: Really, it's pretty clear what foo wanted if you recently spent 15 minutes reading .desktop file specifications. Anyone who could provide an answer would understand the intent of the question.